# Indexing for uniqueidentifier column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, clustered-index

i have created a table where i used unique identifier(GUID) as a primary key of table. Now i need to create a indexing on my table which one will be best for me..i am going to use this table for error logging.

Following is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[errors](
[error_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[assembly_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[method_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[person_id] [int] NULL,
[timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
[description] [varchar](max) NULL,
[parameter_list] [varchar](max) NULL,
[exception_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

So which table i use as a primary key and index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `uniqueidentifier` as the PK in the first place? How is it generated? Using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` or something else?

Comment: i am generating it form GUID in C# code.

Comment: If is a primary key you must already have an index.

Comment: Yes i'm using that column as a primary key. But from somewhere i listen that it is not good to use uniqueidentifier as a pk.

Comment: So it's good to use default clustered index or need to create another one for that table...i'm using this table for error logging,so in this table update is not possible

Comment: Error logging means is a time series. Most queries will be searching by time interval (entries between `now` and `then`). Time series must be clustered by the time column for efficient range scans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that as PK but not good if you use it as clustered index.In that case the GUID will be copied in all the nc index keys and thus makes them much wider and could cause performance issue.Also, this might cause page spilts which is no good.Wide indexes means more space will be used.If you have used GUID to avoid the last page contention issues try to use some sort of hashing technique to make sure that data goes on diff pages.But in that case you have to use same hashing while selecting form table using PK.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. So can you suggest me how can i create a primary key in my error logging table.

Comment: That depends on lots of things.How your error logging table will be populated?How many times a day?is it causing the last page contention (this will happen when you have simulataneous inserts)? How you will use the table in you select queries? If you just want a distinct record then you can have a GUID as PK if you do not have any other column as PK(which can define the records uniquely). Then based on your queries you can have a clustered index. To have a proper clustered index and other indices you need to look at all your change pattern(DML) as well as your query pattern.

Comment: i have added my table structure in question.please review it and try to suggest me best one to use as a primary key and indexing

Comment: By look of table you will be just inserting the data into the table.How many insert say per sec or minute you expect?Will you provide updates on this table? How about the deletes? How the table will be queried,like select statement and how frequently?

Comment: Normally entries are 5 per minute. No we had not provided update on this table. We are just inserting and selecting records from it. Select are also max 5 times per minute.